# For loop if statement syntax error

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have syntax error in my code to move files if the statement is true.The code goes on forever.Also tried adding quotes but unable to.I know there would be some silly mistake that I am doing.

```
for file in *.sort; 
do if [`wc -l` $i -eq 57817]; 
then mv "$i" "../$i"; 
fi; done
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: www.shellcheck.net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You need a space between `[` and the conditions
2. `$i` is not being set
3. Your command substitution does not include the entire command (`wc -l file` is the entire command, you are only wrapping around `wc -l`)
4. `wc -l file` will output the number of lines and the filename which will cause an error.  `wc -l <file` could be used to avoid this

```bsh
for file in *.sort; do 
  if [ "$(wc -l <"$file")" -eq 57817 ]; then 
    mv "$file" "../$file"
  fi
done
```